# Journey Builder - Engagement Split issue

Tags: journeybuilder

When activating a journey with Engagement Split, I receive this error:

> Configuration Not Complete. I18N_VALIDATION_CONFIG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE.

Has anyone been able to overcome this error?